# How to pass both this.state and this.props to routes using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't figure out how to access a method from a parent ReactJS component within my `post` route and  component. Using `react-router`.

This is in 
`<RouteHandler {...this.state} />`

The method/function `pushToPostList()` in  adds a post object to an array, held in `this.state.myList`.

Trying to get my `<Post />` component working so it calls `this.props.pushToPostList(newPost)` to update this.state.myList in `<App />`

Router is:

```
var routes = (
  <Route handler={App} >
    <DefaultRoute handler={SignUp} />
    <Route name="feed" path="feed" handler={LatestFeed} />
    <Route name="post" path="post" handler={Post} pushToPostList={this.pushToPostList} />
  </Route>
);


Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.body );
});
```

More code:

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            myList: []
        };
    },

    pushToPostList: function (object) {
        if (object) { 
          var myTempPosts = this.state.myPostList;
          myTempPosts.push(object); 
          this.setState( {myPostList: myTempPosts} );
        }
    },

    render: function() {        
        return (
            <div>
                <RouteHandler {...this.state} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Post = React.createClass({

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var myPostTxt = this.refs.myPostTxt.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        this.props.pushToPostList( myPostTxt ); // Send object to parent ReactJS component.

    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                Post.

                <textarea 
                  ref="myPostTxt" />

                <p />
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Post</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move pushToPostList={this.pushToPostList} to the App Class.

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        myList: []
    };
},

pushToPostList: function (object) {
    if (object) { 
      var myTempPosts = this.state.myPostList;
      myTempPosts.push(object); 
      this.setState( {myPostList: myTempPosts} );
    }
},

render: function() {        
    return (
        <div>
            <RouteHandler {...this.state} pushToPostList={this.pushToPostList} />
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, just kind of Global. Any way to prevent all my routes from having access to `this.pushToPostList`, except just the 1 route/component that needs it? Flux?

Comment: Move that functionality from the App-class to the Post-class or create a new one in between if you have more than just the Post-class that needs those functions.

Comment: It's not just up and down, I need to move data side-ways between routes. i.e. right now my App hold state of my social feed, and each route will have different view on the feed, i.e. post route, view all route, and view one route. So not sure how a class in between would look/work.

Comment: Ok, then is Flux a good start. Let Stores hold your feed-data so you can request it from multiple components.