# How to recover state on back button with react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If I have a simple react component that records a click count for a button and on each click records a new history state without changing the URL. When the user clicks back how do I restore the state to as it was?

I can do as it is here using the native JavaScript history object, but it fails when the user transitions back to the first state and back from a different component into the last state of this one.

I suspect that there is a better to do this using react-router (1.0)?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    clickCount: 0,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    window.onpopstate = (event) => {
      if (event.state.clickCount) {
        this.setState({ clickCount: event.state.clickCount });
      }
    };
  }

  onClick() {
    const newClickCount = this.state.clickCount + 1;
    const newState = { clickCount: newClickCount };
    this.setState(newState);
    history.pushState(newState, '');
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
        <div>Clicked {this.state.clickCount} times</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: checkout browser history in react-router.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442206/how-to-pass-both-this-state-and-this-props-to-routes-using-react-router) help.

Comment: You can use localStorage for your state. Why not?

Answer (score 4):

localStorage or even cookies are options, but probably not the best way. You should store the count in a database, this way you can set the initial state in your constructor to the last value saved in the database.

Another option, if you only need to persist the count on the client-side(and not in a database) is using a closure.

```
// CountStore.js
var CountStore = (function() {
  var count = 0;

  var incrementCount = function() {
    count += 1;
    return count;
  };

  var getCount = function() {
    return count;
  };

  return {
    incrementCount: incrementCount,
    getCount: getCount
  }

})();

export default CountStore;
```

So your code would change to the below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CountStore from './CountStore'; 

export default class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    clickCount: CountStore.getCount()
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    window.onpopstate = (event) => {
      if (event.state.clickCount) {
        this.setState({ clickCount: event.state.clickCount });
      }
    };
  }

  onClick() {
    const newClickCount = CountStore.incrementCount();
    const newState = { clickCount: newClickCount };
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
        <div>Clicked {this.state.clickCount} times</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There may be a cleaner way of using `react-router`, but this is an option.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
}

interface State {
    count: number
}

export default class About extends Component<Props, State> {

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount(): void {
        this.setState(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.STATE || {});
    }

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.STATE = this.state;
    }

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0}
    }

    render() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        return <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-evenly", fontSize: "2em"}}>
            <span>Count: {count}</span>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({count: count + 1})}>PLUS ONE</button>
            <NavLink to="/">Redirect to HOME</NavLink>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @BaiJiFeiLong, please explain a little more. explanation and code cause to your code will be understood better. maybe have more upvote. I leave an upvote to your post. good luck.

Comment: I think this is storing the instance state on the class prototype. A little weird but very neat.

Comment: I think this is storing the instance state on the class prototype. I guess that there should probably only ever be max 1 instance or they could interfere.  A little weird but very neat. I am using it to persist the state of page A when routing to page B and then back to A. react-router unmounts A which means that its state would be lost. This is the neatest solution I have seen so far for persisting A's state across unmount/didmount . Are there any neater solutions?